# Convert raster to polygon using Image Analysis function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, image-analysis

After many years I discovered the power of Image Analysis functions. They work much faster than similar raster calculations.

However I am struggling with one of the function called Pixel-To-Vector:

[image]

As one can see there is an option to derive polygons, but no matter inputs, it always creates points, even with 1 bit raster:

[image]

Anybody knows how to force polygon creation?